# Overlap horizontalBar graps using ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I'm using https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js to display my graphs in my application. There's one feature that i want to do in my graph. I want to overlap the graphs to get the following results

[image: Sample Graph]

I need to get the display graph in the green box. As for now i only have red box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do this in chart.js, its called stacking. You just need to set the `stacked` option to true.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    stacked: true
  }]
}
```

Note, you might have to set the `yAxes` option instead since this is horizontal.  You can read more about it [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options) and see a sample [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/bar/bar-stacked.html).  I will update my answer with a working codepen example when I get back to a computer.

Comment: Yes. I've already done it. yAxes->stacked->true and xAxes->stacked->false. Thank you for your reply :) (y)